# How do i get the 'head' of all files in a specified directory?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command

I am a beginner to UNIX. Im trying to create a bash script that lists the 'head' of every file in a specified directory but ive tried everything and it doesnt seem to work. How would i do it. Below is the code i currently have in my script. I intent to add more to the script later on but need this to work first.

```
numberOfLines=$1
directoryName=$2

head $numberOfLines $directoryName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
head $directoryName/* -n $numberOfLines
```

Answer (score 1):

Head works on a file (or group of files), not a directory, so you need to adjust your directoryName variable so that you're telling the shell interpreter you mean "every file in this directory" and not a directory.

The easiest way would be to add "/*" to the directoryName, changing your third line to this:

```
head $numberOfLines ${directoryName}/*
```

Example:

```
myshell:tmp gdalton$ ./script.sh -2 hello
==> hello/file1 <==
file 1

==> hello/file2 <==
file 2
file 2
```

Note that you will need to invoke your first parameter with the dash as I did in the example because of the syntax for the head command. You could easily fix this in your code using the change I made to fix your code as a jumping point... I'd strongly advise you check the man pages for head so you can figure out how to structure your shell commands; they often contain a wealth of options for these commands.

```
man head
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the head command in a wrong way.
Compare your code to the [manual page](http://ss64.com/bash/head.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `find` command:

```
find "$directory" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec head -n "$numberOfLines" {} \;
```

This ensures that `head` will be executed only on files and not directories.